# How can one tell apart the words queen and quean in a conversation?

Tags: pronunciation

I tried online voice synthesis and it sounds indistinguishable to my Russian ear: https://translate.google.com/#en/ru/quean%20vs%20queen

How am I supposed to pick up the difference if the context in which they are used can very well be interchangeable and there is no apparent difference in how they sound?

Comment: Related: [How is quean related to queen?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/460601/how-is-quean-related-to-queen)

Comment: What do you suppose "quean" to mean?  I've never seen that spelling. Could you give a context where they could be confused.

Answer (score 3):

You can only tell 'queen' and 'quean' apart by context in conversation, because they are homophones. However, this is of little importance, since nobody says 'quean', ever, outside of games of Scrabble. It is so archaic that the overwhelming majority of native speakers are unaware of it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in the pronunciation of these two words. Both are pronounced /kwiːn/. You can only distinguish which word is being used by the context in which it is being used. Quean, in the second definition given below, is now regarded as archaic, and is not commonly heard in modern conversation.

Queen - a female monarch, wife of a king, chess piece.

Quean - disreputable woman, prostitute; impudent or badly behaved girl

Quine or quean - (in some places within Scotland) - a young or unmarried woman